# Inserting a date from a cell into a Pivot table to use it as a filter

Tags: vba, excel, date, format

Im very new to VBA. I will explain my project.

I have an Excel sheet with a lot of information that I want to filter. For the moment my code looks like this:

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tableau croisé dynamique2").PivotFields( _
        "CREATION_DATE")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
    End With

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tableau croisé dynamique2").AddDataField ActiveSheet. _
    PivotTables("Tableau croisé dynamique2").PivotFields("AMOUNT"), _
    "Nombre de AMOUNT", xlCount

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tableau croisé dynamique2").PivotFields("STATUS")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tableau croisé dynamique2").PivotFields( _
    "VENDOR_NAME")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 2
End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tableau croisé dynamique2").PivotFields( _
    "INVOICE_NUM")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 3
End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tableau croisé dynamique2").PivotFields( _
    "Nombre de AMOUNT")
    .Caption = "Somme de AMOUNT"
    .Function = xlSum
End With

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tableau croisé dynamique2").PivotFields( _
    "CREATION_DATE").CurrentPage = "08/09/2016"
```

This code works to extract to filter with the date 08/09/2016.
Now, I would like to make the pivot table get this date in a cell ahead of launching the code.

But I don't want to have to go in to the code every time to change the date I want.

I would like something like this:
Ex: I write "09/09/2016" in cell "A1"

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tableau croisé dynamique2").PivotFields( _
        "CREATION_DATE").CurrentPage = "A1"
```

But I am getting a debugging error.

Comment: `.CurrentPage = Range("A1").Value2` ... you may need to wrap a `CDate()` around it.

Comment: Thank you for your respons, but it doesnt seem to work. What do you mean with wrap Cdate() around it?

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tableau croisé dynamique2").PivotFields( _
        "CREATION_DATE").CurrentPage = Range(CDate("'Sheet_date'!A1")).Value2

Comment: Scott was saying that if `... .CurrentPage = Range("A1").Value2` doesn't work, try using `... .CurrentPage = CDate(Range("A1").Value2)`.  (CDate converts a value to a date.)  But it may actually want a string so, if neither of Scott's suggestions work, try `... .CurrentPage = Format(CDate(Range("A1").Value2),"dd/mm/yyyy")` (or "mm/dd/yyyy" - depending on what format that date is meant to be in).

Comment: @Thistlepower try the code in my answer below, and let me know if it worked

Comment: Thank you! This code worked!

.CurrentPage = Format(CDate(Range("A1").Value2),"dd/mm/yyyy")

Answer (score 0):

After some testing,  I found the cause (on my Excel Book). It was related to formatting the Pivot Field "**CREATION_DATE**", once I added the following section it worked.

```
Set PvtFld = PvtTbl.PivotFields("CREATION_DATE")
With PvtFld
    .Orientation = xlPageField
    .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"  ' << this line
    .Position = 1
End With
```

And for the full code:

```
Sub PivotFilterDate()

Dim PvtTbl              As PivotTable
Dim PvtFld              As PivotField

' set your Pivot Table (after created) to a variable
Set PvtTbl = Sheets("PivotSpanish").PivotTables("Tableau croisé dynamique2")

' Set "CREATION_DATE" to a Pivot Field variable 
Set PvtFld = PvtTbl.PivotFields("CREATION_DATE")
With PvtFld
    .Orientation = xlPageField
    .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    .Position = 1
End With

' you can modify your code to change all field setting, like following 2:
With PvtTbl.PivotFields("STATUS")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With

With PvtTbl.PivotFields("VENDOR_NAME")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 2
End With

' clear previous filters
PvtFld.ClearAllFilters

' --- trapping errors --- 
' added a Boolean Flag to trap scenarios where no Pivot Item found that matches the value in Cell A1
Dim PvtItemExists       As Boolean

PvtItemExists = False

' check all Pivot items in Pivot Field ("CREATION_DATE")
For Each PvtItem In PvtFld.PivotItems
    ' check if current Pivot Item equals the value in Cell A1
    If PvtItem.Value = CStr(CDate(Range("D1").Value)) Then
        PvtItemExists = True
        Exit For
    End If 

Next PvtItem

If PvtItemExists Then
    PvtFld.CurrentPage = CStr(CDate(Range("D1").Value))
Else
    MsgBox "No data matches for date " & CDate(Range("D1").Value) & " in Pivot Table", vbCritical
End If    

End Sub
```

Comment: @Thistlepower  You're welcome, please mark as answer and upvote